# Camera permission keeps being denied on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, camera

This code is requesting camera permission to initialize camera to use it later, it works fine on Android, but on iOS the permission keeps being denied on its own without showing permission request dialogue box

```
  void _initCamera() async {
    if (await PermissionsService().hasCameraPermission()) {
      setState(() {
        isCameraPermissionGranted = true;
      });
      print('camera permission granted');
    } else {
      bool isGranted = await PermissionsService().requestCameraPermission(
          onPermissionDenied: () {
        AppUtil.showAlertDialog(
          context: context,
          heading: 'info',
          message:
              'You must grant this camera access to be able to use this feature.',
          firstBtnText: 'Give Permission',
          firstFunc: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            await _initCamera();
          },
          secondBtnText: 'Leave',
          secondFunc: () async {
            print('camera permission denied');
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        );
      });
      setState(() {
        isCameraPermissionGranted = isGranted;
      });
      return;
    }

    if (isCameraPermissionGranted) {
      //initialization code
  }
```

any idea why this behavior happens?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in info.plist file in Runner folder of iOS this will give camera access permission to iOS app

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```